# Android Button to open URL

Tags: android

I have two button which starts new intents, and they are working fine.
In the same activity i am now trying to make a new button that opens a URL link, but i cant make it work.

The two buttons starting new intents, are btn_Calender and btn_Info. So the new button which should open URL is btn_button4.

Can someone plese see my code and tell me what i am doing wrong.

Thank you all.

```
 package com.xxxxxx;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.net.Uri;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;

  import com.chrfugl.stubhuset.R;

  public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Button btn_Calender, btn_Info, btn_button4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    btn_Calender = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Calender);
    btn_Info = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Info);
    btn_button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

    btn_Calender.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_Info.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_button4.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View view) {

    Intent intent;

    switch (view.getId()) {

    case R.id.btn_Calender:

        intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        break;

    case R.id.btn_Info:

        intent = new Intent(this,InfoActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        break;

    case R.id.button4:

        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);

        break;
    }

}
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your switch statement in your `onClick` is wrong..

The ID of your button is R.id.button4:

```
btn_button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
```

In your onClick you are checking for the ID:

```
case R.id.btn_button4:
```

Which means you never reach your call.. The `Intent` itself is correct.

**EDIT**

Replace `case R.id.btn_button4:` with `case R.id.button4:` in your `onClick`-method